# Low Pass Filter on TF Keras Model Inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, linear-regression, onnx

Is there a method to apply a low pass filter on inputs for a Keras model? I have 4 inputs of noisy sensor data, and I'm curious if I can build it into the model before I export it for Inference with ONNX, or if I need to filter it outside the model.

I'm pretty new to ML, but currently my model works perfect when running the Low Pass prior to the model. My goal would be to limit user error by being able to attach the model directly to the sensor output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but since you're using Keras, you can include a Lambda layer between your Input Layer and the rest of your model. The Lambda layer lets you run arbitrary Tensorflow code on model inputs, so in theory you could implement your filter in this Lambda layer, provided it is something you can do with the Tensorflow primitives.
For instance, consider the following code:

```
input_layer = keras.Layers.Input(shape=(signal_length,no_channels))
sig_diff = keras.Layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1:] - x[:,:-1])(input_layer)
conv_1 = keras.Layers.Conv1D(5)(sig_diff)
#rest of model goes here
```

In this very trivial example, I'm differencing the input signal before passing it to some sort of convolutional model. You might be able to implement your low pass filter in the lambda layer as above, which should solve the problem.